# Problema de lógica al comprobar elementos

Tags: javascript, lógica

Desde un array vacío se crea un div con tres input.

```js
let array = [];

if (array.length == 0) {
  createElements();
}

function createElements() {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.setAttribute('class', 'content');
  div.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  div.style.width = '500px';
  div.style.height = '50px';
  document.body.append(div);

  let Finp = document.createElement('input');
  Finp.setAttribute('class', 'F-uno');
  let Sinp = document.createElement('input');
  Sinp.setAttribute('class', 'S-dos');
  let Tinp = document.createElement('input');
  Tinp.setAttribute('class', 'T-tres');

  div.append(Finp, Sinp, Tinp);

  Finp.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    if (Finp.value == '' && Sinp.value == '' && Tinp.value == '' && document.querySelectorAll('.content').length > 1) {
      div.remove();
    } else if (Finp.value != '' /*&& checkVacuum == 'true'*/ ) {
      createElements();
    }
  });

  Sinp.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    if (Sinp.value == '' && Finp.value == '' && Tinp.value == '' && document.querySelectorAll('.content').length > 1) {
      div.remove();
    }
  });

  Tinp.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    if (Tinp.value == '' && Sinp.value == '' && Finp.value == '' && document.querySelectorAll('.content').length > 1) {
      div.remove();
    }
  });
}
```

El caso es que, necesito hacer lo siguiente (mal reflejado en los eventos de los input):

- Si el valor del primer input de un div, es cambiado (event change), tiene que crear otro div con tres input abajo del todo. (Yo lo hago activando la función createElements())
- Si el ultimo div de todos, tiene los valores input vacíos, no se pueden crear más divs debajo.
- Si borras el valor de los 3 input de un div, dicho div se borrará del DOM (eso está hecho)

Con estas tres premisas, consigo hacer la primera y la última, pero la segunda me trae un problema de lógica severo para lo que es mi cabecita pensante.

Intenté solventarlo con la función checkVacuum():

```
function checkVacuum(){
    let elm = document.querySelectorAll('.content');
    let n = elm.length-1;

    if(elm[n].querySelectorAll('input')[0].value == '' && elm[n].querySelectorAll('input')[1].value == '' && elm[n].querySelectorAll('input')[2].value == ''){
        return true;
    }
}
```

Pero hace que, como el primer div de todos tiene los 3 input vacíos, y al ser el primero es el ultimo ya que es el único, y no se añaden más input.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo? No se me ocurre nada. Lo peor es que sabría hacerlo sintácticamente pero no morfológicamente

Answer (score 1):

Vale, ya lo tengo, solo bastaba con comprobar también en checkVacuum si el ultimo div era el primero y listo:

```js
let array = [];

if (array.length == 0) {
  createElements();
}

function createElements() {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.setAttribute('class', 'content');
  div.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  div.style.width = '500px';
  div.style.height = '50px';
  document.body.append(div);

  let Finp = document.createElement('input');
  Finp.setAttribute('class', 'F-uno');
  let Sinp = document.createElement('input');
  Sinp.setAttribute('class', 'S-dos');
  let Tinp = document.createElement('input');
  Tinp.setAttribute('class', 'T-tres');

  div.append(Finp, Sinp, Tinp);

  Finp.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    let chk = checkVacuum();
    console.log(chk);

    if (Finp.value == '' && Sinp.value == '' && Tinp.value == '' && document.querySelectorAll('.content').length > 1) {
      div.remove();
    } else if (Finp.value != '' && chk != true) {
      createElements();
    }
  });

  Sinp.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    if (Sinp.value == '' && Finp.value == '' && Tinp.value == '' && document.querySelectorAll('.content').length > 1) {
      div.remove();
    } else if (Finp.value != '') {
      createElements();
    }
  });

  Tinp.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    if (Tinp.value == '' && Sinp.value == '' && Finp.value == '' && document.querySelectorAll('.content').length > 1) {
      div.remove();
    } else if (Finp.value != '') {
      createElements();
    }
  });
}

function checkVacuum() {
  let elm = document.querySelectorAll('.content');
  let n = elm.length - 1;

  if (elm[n].querySelectorAll('input')[0].value == '' && elm[n].querySelectorAll('input')[1].value == '' && elm[n].querySelectorAll('input')[2].value == '' && elm[n] != elm[0]) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Puedes marcarlo como respuesta

Comment: Hasta dentro de dos dias no me deja